# Laravel 9 - passing data for every view from one controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-9

Hello i'm new in laravel. My application has a search bar component in almost every view.
The user types there the ID of the client, makes a query to db and compares the user's typed ID with the DB client ID.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
 {
   function get_kcli(Request $request) {
    
    $id = $request->input('kcli');
    $current_page = $request->input('currentPage') . '.index';
    $data = DB::connection('oracle')->table('CLIENTS')->where('KCLI', $id)->get();

   return view($current_page, compact('data'));       
  }
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::post('/search', [App\Http\Controllers\SearchController::class, 'get_kcli'])->name('search');
```

Form search component view:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
<form method="POST" class="form-inline position-relative" action="{{ route('/search') }}">
    @csrf
    @method('POST')
  <input class="form-control shadow-none" name="kcli" id="kcli" type="number" placeholder="Codice..." aria-label="Search">
  <input type="text" name="currentPage" value="{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}" hidden>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light search-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Anyone knows the best practice to store that data request globally an mantain it for every view that need to exctract it?

Example : I search for the client ID '5', the search controller makes a db query with the passed ID, then compacts data. That data has to be stored globally for get the results and post it in other views, without searching again on every view switch(the typed ID '5' has to remain in the search field on every view switch).

Comment: You can store that client ID in session and fetch it any where

Comment: have you considered adding the ID into session, and then using a view composer to query the database on every request

Comment: You have to place conditions, First run your query once and store it to cache or session and if data is already there don't run the query

Comment: @SavanSolanki
thank you very much that was the exact thing i was looking for!
I have to dig deeper but it's working!

Answer (score 0):

To print client_id you can store that "id" in session and print from the session by this way your search value keep remains and to get data in all views there is the concept View::share you can register that in AppServiceProvider please go through this link

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views